# CNN model gives accuracy 0f 90% on Validation Images but when predicted on the same validation set, accuracy is hardly 5%

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN. I was implementing CNN to classify a dataset with 18000 training images and 10,000 test images into 102 output classes.
I am using Transfer learning and i can see that training accuracy is around 98% and Validation accuracy is around 97%. But when i predict on the same validation dataset, i hardly get 5% accuracy.
I tried L1/L2 regularizarion in Dense layers as looks like overfitting case.
I tried dropouts But didn't able to get more accuracy than 5-6% on Validation dataset itself. Needed some suggestions and input here.
Validation Dataset i had created out of train dataset by randomly selecting 50 images of each of the 102 classes , so validation dataset contains around 5000 images. Below is the code

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input

base_model=MobileNet(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)
x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.3),activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(1024,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.3), activation='relu')(x)
preds=Dense(102,activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)

for layer in model.layers[:44]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[44:]:
    layer.trainable=True

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input) 

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./train', 
                                                 target_size=(224,224),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 shuffle=True)
validation_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

validation_generator=validation_datagen.flow_from_directory('./Validation', 
                                                 target_size=(224,224),
                                                 color_mode='rgb',
                                                 batch_size=32,
                                                 class_mode='categorical',
                                                 shuffle=True)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
MobileNet=model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                   steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                              validation_steps=validation_generator.n // validation_generator.batch_size,
                   epochs=30)
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `validation_generator`?

Comment: Added the code for Validation_generator